# Why does assigning FOR XML to an XML variable warn about CONVERT_IMPLICIT(XML)?

Tags: execution-plan, xml, type-conversion, t-sql

```
SET STATISTICS XML ON;
DECLARE @x XML = (SELECT 'hi' "@id" FOR XML PATH ('this'), root ('xml'));
```

> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(xml,[Expr1001],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

Why is a conversion happening? I thought that `FOR XML` caused the result to be the `XML` type already. If this warning can/should be ignored, how do I stop the warning from appearing in the execution plan (so that when I debug a bigger query with a similar warning it doesn’t distract me from actual issues)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of the `FOR XML PATH` expression is `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, not `XML`.

I was being confused by the fact that SSMS renders any column named `XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B` as if it has the `XML` data type. If I run the following command, I get a clickable XML result cell in SSMS:

```
SELECT 'hi' "@id" FOR XML PATH ('this'), root ('xml');
```

I was able to figure out the actual type by getting SQL Server to spit out a type-conversion error:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY((SELECT 'hi' "@id" FOR XML PATH ('this'), root ('xml')), 'BaseType');
```

> ```
> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with sql_variant
> ```

To fix the warning completely, simply [add the `TYPE` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms190025.aspx) to the `FOR XML` clause:

```
SET STATISTICS XML ON;
DECLARE @x XML = (SELECT 'hi' "@id" FOR XML PATH ('this'), root ('xml'), TYPE);
```